# Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "*": expected selector, was "= require boots..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, production-environment

I am getting below error when doing assets:precompile using `ruby 2.4.3` and `rails 5.1.4`

> Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "*": expected selector, was "=
>   require boots..."

`RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`

application.scss file contents as below.

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require datetimepicker
 *= require chosen
 *= require reports_kit/application
 *= require_tree
 *= require_self
 */

 @import "patternfly-sprockets";
 @import "patternfly";
 @import 'timepiece';
```

#### Error msg on terminal

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
** Execute assets:precompile
rails aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "*": expected selector, was "= require boots..."
(sass):3333
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1207:in `expected'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1137:in `expected'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:21:in `parse_selector'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:428:in `visit_rule'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `block in visit'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/home/fabritronix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following for best practice

Remove below lines from `application.scss`

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require datetimepicker
 *= require chosen
 *= require reports_kit/application
 *= require_tree
 *= require_self
 */
```

and if you need the libraries then create a file inside `stylesheets` folder like `custom.css` and put those CSS libraries here and make sure your typo is right like `*= require_tree .`

OR you can rewrite your `application.scss` to `application.css.scss` correct the typo like `*= require_tree .`

Hope to help

Comment: Why should we need to place the custom.css in javascripts folder instead of stylesheet folder ?

Comment: I have created two files application.scss and custom.css and placed respective code. Now in production mode it compiles properly but css is not working on html.  Even in development mode it does not render the css after the change as you mentioned above.

Comment: The issue is in bootstrap.css file as shown below.         $ sass -c app/assets/stylesheets/**.css*
Error: Invalid CSS after "*": expected selector, was "= require boots..."
        on line 2 of app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css
  Use --trace for backtrace. Its content are ###############   //= require bootstrap-select
*= require bootstrap/alert
*= require bootstrap/dropdown
############

Comment: Anyway I resolved it by removing the bootstrap.css file and its gem as well.

Comment: Great @KiranPatil